# force the text to start in the second column of a two-column document

Tags: chapters, two-column, scrbook

can someone help me to do the following?

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,spanish,10pt, letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\setlength\parindent{15pt}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\newlength\imargin
\newlength\omargin
\setlength\imargin{3.2cm}
\setlength\omargin{2.5cm}
\geometry{
  inner  = \imargin ,
  outer  = \omargin ,
  top    = 2.5cm ,
  bottom = 2cm
}
\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\definecolor{logo1}{HTML}{425C00}
\definecolor{logo2}{HTML}{FFFF10}
\definecolor{logo3}{HTML}{425C00}
\definecolor{logo4}{HTML}{854DC1} % Color de la ley de ohm
\colorlet{mygray}{black!20} % 
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\newcommand*\logo{%
  \textcolor{logo1}{\scalebox{1.3}{Itm} \scalebox{2}{Ing. electrónica}} \\
  d20\scalebox{2}{MODERN}}
\tikzset{
  logo1/.style={
    color = mygray ,
    font  = \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries ,
    inner sep = .25in ,
    align = center
  },
  page/.style={
    color  = white ,
    fill   = logo1 ,
    font   = \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ,
    minimum size = \omargin-.2in ,
    yshift = 2in
  },
  chapter/.style={
    color = mygray ,
    scale = 1.5 ,
    transform shape ,
    font  = \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ,
  }
}
\ohead{

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[below left,logo1] at (current page.north east)}
   {\node[below right,logo1] at (current page.north west)}
   {\logo1};

 % page number:
 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[left,page] at (current page.east)}
   {\node[right,page] at (current page.west)}
   {\thepage} ;
 % chapter mark:
 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[anchor=north east,rotate=-90,chapter] at (current page.south east)}
   {\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,chapter] at (current page.south west)}
   {Ing. Electrónica} ;
 \ifthispageodd
   {
     \draw[mygray,very thin]
       (current page.south east)++(-.6in,0)--++(0,.6\paperheight) ;
   }
   {
     \draw[mygray,very thin]
       (current page.south west)++(.6in,0)--++(0,.6\paperheight) ;
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\ifthispageodd
{}
{}
{};

}

\usepackage{charter}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\selectfont}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\selectfont}

\newlength{\chapterfontsize}
\setlength{\chapterfontsize}{30pt}
\newlength{\sectionfontsize}
\setlength{\sectionfontsize}{14pt}
\newlength{\subsectionfontsize}
\setlength{\subsectionfontsize}{12pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\fontsize{\chapterfontsize}{\chapterfontsize}}%
  {\newpage}
  {0pt}
  {% <-- REMOVED INDENTATION
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[mygray] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south);
        \draw (current page.north) ++(0,-2in) node[white,fill=logo1,inner sep=0.20em,align=center,minimum width=.55\textwidth](chapapp){{}{{\chapapp\space\thechapter:}}};
        \node[anchor=north,white,fill=logo1!85,inner sep=.25em,xshift=-.6in]
        at (chapapp.south)
        {\scalebox{1}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}\hspace*{.2in}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{1cm}
    }%
%--------
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I can not get the text of the chapters to start in the right column
[image]

Comment: Try putting `\null\newpage` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, but there is some way to add these commands so that it is done automatically every time a chapter is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I will give is not that good I think, but it perfectly works:

```
    \documentclass[twocolumn,spanish,10pt, letterpaper,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,americanresistors]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{array}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} 
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\setlength\parindent{15pt}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\newlength\imargin
\newlength\omargin
\setlength\imargin{3.2cm}
\setlength\omargin{2.5cm}
\geometry{
  inner  = \imargin ,
  outer  = \omargin ,
  top    = 2.5cm ,
  bottom = 2cm
}
\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\bf}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\mathbf}
\definecolor{logo1}{HTML}{425C00}
\definecolor{logo2}{HTML}{FFFF10}
\definecolor{logo3}{HTML}{425C00}
\definecolor{logo4}{HTML}{854DC1} % Color de la ley de ohm
\colorlet{mygray}{black!20} % 
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\newcommand*\logo{%
  \textcolor{logo1}{\scalebox{1.3}{Itm} \scalebox{2}{Ing. electrónica}} \\
  d20\scalebox{2}{MODERN}}
\tikzset{
  logo1/.style={
    color = mygray ,
    font  = \normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries ,
    inner sep = .25in ,
    align = center
  },
  page/.style={
    color  = white ,
    fill   = logo1 ,
    font   = \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ,
    minimum size = \omargin-.2in ,
    yshift = 2in
  },
  chapter/.style={
    color = mygray ,
    scale = 1.5 ,
    transform shape ,
    font  = \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries ,
  }
}
\ohead{

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[below left,logo1] at (current page.north east)}
   {\node[below right,logo1] at (current page.north west)}
   {\logo1};

 % page number:
 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[left,page] at (current page.east)}
   {\node[right,page] at (current page.west)}
   {\thepage} ;
 % chapter mark:
 \ifthispageodd
   {\node[anchor=north east,rotate=-90,chapter] at (current page.south east)}
   {\node[anchor=north west,rotate=90,chapter] at (current page.south west)}
   {Ing. Electrónica} ;
 \ifthispageodd
   {
     \draw[mygray,very thin]
       (current page.south east)++(-.6in,0)--++(0,.6\paperheight) ;
   }
   {
     \draw[mygray,very thin]
       (current page.south west)++(.6in,0)--++(0,.6\paperheight) ;
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\ifthispageodd
{}
{}
{};

}

\usepackage{charter}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{charter}
\definecolor{mybluei}{RGB}{28,138,207}
\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{131,197,231}

\newcommand\ChapterFont{\selectfont}
\newcommand\SectionFont{\selectfont}

\newlength{\chapterfontsize}
\setlength{\chapterfontsize}{30pt}
\newlength{\sectionfontsize}
\setlength{\sectionfontsize}{14pt}
\newlength{\subsectionfontsize}
\setlength{\subsectionfontsize}{12pt}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\ChapterFont\fontsize{\chapterfontsize}{\chapterfontsize}}%
  {\newpage}
  {0pt}
  {% <-- REMOVED INDENTATION
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[mygray] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south);
        \draw (current page.north) ++(0,-2in) node[white,fill=logo1,inner sep=0.20em,align=center,minimum width=.55\textwidth](chapapp){{}{{\chapapp\space\thechapter:}}};
        \node[anchor=north,white,fill=logo1!85,inner sep=.25em,xshift=-.6in]
        at (chapapp.south)
        {\scalebox{1}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}\hspace*{.2in}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{1cm}
    }%
%--------

 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK
 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK
 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK
\newcommand{\starthalfpage}{\quad \\[50em]}
 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK
 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK
 %%%%% THIS MAKES IT WORK

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
 % USING THE MACRO
\starthalfpage

\lipsum[1-10]
\section{test}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

(nice layout by the way :-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I wanted this to be done automatically every time a chapter is created.

Comment: Maybe redefining the \chapter command with \starthalfpage in it? (did you noticed that on the second chapter, the gray space is crossing the text?)

Comment: I will try, and what you mention about the gray box in the even chapters. I could solve it by changing the margins. Although I need to find the way I always take the settings of an odd chapter regardless of whether the sheet is odd or even.